# Can you require a separate method be called when a static method is called?

Tags: java, exception, methods, static

In this situation, I have a class with methods that get called to perform certain actions, but I want to make sure a certain condition is true before proceeding.
e.g.

```
public class ActionClass {

    public static void checkCondition() {
        if(!condition) throw new RuntimeException();
    }


    public static void performAction() {
        checkCondition();

        ...
    }
}
```

I realize I could make all these methods non-static and use a constructor as a place to perform this condition check and throw an exception there if needed, but I'm curious if there are any other ways to do the same thing?

Comment: There are `static initialization blocks` which may be suitable depending on what's required (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), but I'm not a big fan - going with non-static and a constructor is typically the far better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check a condition every time a method is run, then this is really the only practical way to do it.

Even if you made all the methods non-static, the constructor would only be called once, and the methods would be free to run without the condition check if the check was satisfied at the instantiation of the object.